# Access sub class constant in static parent method

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, static

Is it possible to access a child class constant from within a static method in the parent class?

```
public class Model  {

    public static void someMethod(){
        HERE I WANT TO GET THE MODEL_NAME constant!
    }
}

public class EventModel extends Model {
    public static final String MODEL_NAME = "events";
}
```

and in some other place I call:

```
EventModel.someMethod();
```

Comment: Give an example. I'm wary of any parent that needs to know about its child; ask my dad.

Comment: Having posted my answer below, I must say I also agree with Dave Newton. If your parent class needs to know about it's child, you MAY have a design issue to consider (but not always . . .)

Comment: Can you present a situation where this is not a design issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it!

If the constant is declared `private`, then no. If it is `public`, then yes, as anyone can access it. The parent class is largely irrelevent here.

```
class Parent {
    public static void Foo() {
        int x = Child.YEP;    // Ok
        int y = Child.NOPE;   // Error
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public  static final int YEP  = 42;
    private static final int NOPE = 66;
}
```

`Foo` is defined in `Parent`, and thus cannot access private members of `Child`.

How about this?

```
class Parent {
    abstract String getModelName();

    public void someMethod() {
        String myModel = getModelName();
    }
}

class Child extend Parent {
    String getModelName() { return "events"; }
}
```

Note however, that the method is no longer public.

Comment: A method name **must** start with lower case letter.

Comment: `Foo()` should be `foo()`.. It is impolite to don't follow the Java naming rules. I tried to edit the post instead of commenting but I couldn't.

Comment: Why? It compiles just fine as-is on
Eclipse Java Compiler 0.894_R34x, 3.4.2 release

Answer (score 1):

You might find this more effective.

Define your parent class with a method getName. Note that this can be public, if you want your model class to expose a Name property, otherwise, you can keep it as "protected" as I have here. "Protected" will keep the method visible within this class, and any derived (child) classes.

```
public class Model {
    private static String MODEL_NAME = "Model";

    protected String getModelName(){
        return MODEL_NAME;
    }       
}
```

Then define an "override" for the name method on your child class:

```
public class EventModel extends Model
{
    private static String MODEL_NAME = "events";

    @Override // Tells the compiler that this method OVERRIDES the parent method
    public String getModelName(){
        return MODEL_NAME;
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs the way I suspect you are trying to acheive . . .

EDIT: Oooh. NOW I see the problem. Missed that you needed to reference that from a static method . . .

Comment: Bad answer above. I missed the fact that you needed to access this from a static method on the parent. My bad . . .